# cannot find symbol -- symbol : method lastIndexOf(java.lang.String) location: class java.util.Scanner

Tags: java, find, compiler-errors, symbols

My code tries to extract a filename to load a file from reading another file that contains the filename:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    Scanner scan;
    String transFilename;
    String filename;

    scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the name of your transaction file please (include .txt extension): ");
    transFilename = scan.nextLine();
    scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(transFilename));

    filename = readLine.next(2,readLine.lastIndexOf(""));    
    Scanner input = new Scanner( new FileReader(filename));   
}
```

the Error generated:

```
blah.java:72: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method lastIndexOf(java.lang.String)
location: class java.util.Scanner
            filename = readLine.next(2,readLine.lastIndexOf(""));    
                                               ^
1 error
```

The same error is generated when i tried to use ".length" method that should be built into java...

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include readLine scanner, which has been initialized.  Scanner readLine;                                              readLine = new Scanner(scan.nextLine());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `readLine` is of type `Scanner` and you are trying to invoke `lastIndexOf()`  but thi method doesn't belong to [`Scanner`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class

Answer (score 0):

Your `readLine` is java.util.Scanner... I guess you're thinking that it's a java.lang.String.